# Delete a entity with @OneToOne

Tags: jpa, entity, sql-delete, one-to-one

Hi i having problem with deleting of an entity. The entitymanager would not remove the entity. Do anyone see the error in the code?

Error message:

java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :null
Actual   :Account{id=1, customer=Customer{customerId=1, firstName='Kim', lastName='Pedersen', email='kim@yahoo.no', phoneNumber='90045870', birth=1980-11-05 00:00:00.0}, login= 'Login{Id=1, username='kimPedda', password='kimSimDimSum'}}

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "Account.getAll", query = "select a from Account a")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_ACC", initialValue = 50)
public class Account {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_ACC")
private int id;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)//, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "FK_CUSTOMER")
private Customer customer;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "FK_LOGIN")
private Login login;

    /*
-------------------------------------------
CONSTRUCTORS
-------------------------------------------
        */

public Account(Customer customer, Login login) {
    this.customer = customer;
    this.login = login;
}


public Account() {

}
// ======================================
// =            GET AND SET            =
// ======================================


public Customer getCustomer() {
    return customer;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
}

public Login getLogin() {
    return login;
}

public void setLogin(Login login) {
    this.login = login;
}

// ======================================
// =            TO STRING        =
// ======================================

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Account{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", customer=" + customer +
            ", login= '" + login +
            '}';
}
```

}

```
public class JpaAccountDao implements AccountDao {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "account")
private EntityManager entityManager;

public JpaAccountDao() {
}
public JpaAccountDao(EntityManager entityManager){
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

@Override
public Account persist(Account account) {
    if( account == null )
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No account could be created!");
    entityManager.persist(account);
    return account;
}

@Override
public Boolean delete(int id) {
    if( id != 0) {
        Account account = entityManager.find(Account.class,id);
        entityManager.remove(account);
        return true;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Account with id-nr:{%d] could not be deleted =C ", id ));
}

@Override
public Account findById(int id) {
    if( id <= 0 )
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No id was found!");
    return entityManager.find(Account.class, id);
}

@Override
public List<Account> getAll() {
    TypedQuery<Account> query =     entityManager.createNamedQuery("Account.getAll", Account.class);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

}

public class AccountServiceIT {

```
private EntityManager entityManager;
private EntityManagerFactory factory;
private JpaAccountDao jpaAccountDao;
private JpaCustomerDao jpaCustomerDao;
private CustomerTestCase customerTestCase;
private JpaLoginDao jpaLoginDao;
private Account account;
private Account account2;

@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TEST");
    entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
    jpaAccountDao = new JpaAccountDao(entityManager);
    account = new Account();
    account2 = new Account();
}
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    entityManager.close();
    factory.close();
}

/*
Delete a account popularized via the init.script
 */
// TODO CREATE A TESTE THATS RUNS
@Test
public void deleteAccountTest() throws Exception {
    Account account = entityManager.find(Account.class, 1);
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    boolean result = jpaAccountDao.delete(account.getId());
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

    Account res = jpaAccountDao.findById(1);
    assertEquals(res, account);
    assertNull(result);
}
```

}

(Init.script)

INSERT INTO BOOK (id, title, price, description, number, instantiationDate) VALUES (1,'Mio min Mio', 100.0, 'Book about two brothers', '8-321389213', '2016-05-11 23:42:21');
INSERT INTO BOOK (id, title, price, description, number, instantiationDate ) VALUES (2, 'Franks dagbok', 10.0, 'About the war and Auchwitch', '13-321321321', '2016-11-05 20:00:00' );

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (FK_CUSTOMER, firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber, birth) VALUES (1, 'Kim', 'Pedersen','kim@yahoo.no','90045870', '1980-11-05');
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (FK_CUSTOMER, firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber, birth) VALUES (2, 'Silje', 'Kyrra','silje@yahoo.no','45236585', '1999-1-15');

INSERT INTO LOGIN (FK_LOGIN, username,password ) VALUES (1,'kimPedda', 'kimSimDimSum');
INSERT INTO LOGIN (FK_LOGIN, username,password ) VALUES (2,'Silkyra', 'SanriKorraDigo');

INSERT INTO ACCOUNT (id, FK_CUSTOMER, FK_LOGIN ) VALUES (1, 1, 1 );
INSERT INTO ACCOUNT (id, FK_CUSTOMER, FK_LOGIN ) VALUES (2, 2, 2 );

Comment: Post the code **here**, don't link to it.

Answer (score 0):

I just figure it out. It was an error with my testfile =)

I needed to change the method to get a instance, and delete with the method rather than through entityManager =)

- Case solved